# Object expected error on IE8 with skrollr.min.js plugin

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, cross-browser, parallax

I was trying to create a parallax website with this plugin: 
github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr
and everything works great on all the browsers except of ie8 that shows me this error:

```
Message: Object expected
Line: 2
Char: 5223
Code: 0
URI: http://milokan.com/images/attract/dist/skrollr.min.js
```

but their demo seems to look fine at ie8 http://prinzhorn.github.io/skrollr/
so i don't understand whats the problem with my code.

this is my embed code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.menu.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
//http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/ + tablets
(function(a) {
    if(/android|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(ad|hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|meego.+mobile|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino|playbook|silk/i.test(a) || /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4)))
    {
        //Add skrollr mobile on mobile devices.
        document.write('<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.mobile.min.js"><\/script>');
    }
})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);
</script>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dist/skrollr.ie.min.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var s = skrollr.init(/*other stuff*/);

        //The options (second parameter) are all optional. The values shown are the default values.
        skrollr.menu.init(s, {
            animate: true, //skrollr will smoothly animate to the new position using `animateTo`.
            duration: 2500, //How long the animation should take in ms.
            easing: 'linear' //The easing function to use.
        });
    </script>
```

and this is my demo site with the problem:
http://milokan.com/images/attract/main.html.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting errors in FF as well. The solution is easy:

You copied the skrollr demo and it contains these two lines

```
<div class="drop" style="background:#7e5600;" data-0="right:562px;bottom[WTF]:100%;" data-1500="bottom:0%;">אודות</div>
<div class="drop" style="background:#99D100;" data-0="right:656px;bottom[inverted]:100%;" data-1500="bottom:0%;">צרו קשר</div>
```

But neither `WTF` nor `inverted` easing functions are defined. These are **not** built in. The skrollr demo defines them like this

```
var s = skrollr.init({
    easing: {
        WTF: Math.random,
        inverted: function(p) {
            return 1-p;
        }
    }
});
```